# Using KeyRock outside of FIWARE Lab

Tags: fiware, filab

We're developing a smart cities service and want to use [KeyRock](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm) for our users authentication. We don't want to use existing FIWARE Lab instance though, but create our own. The [FIWARE catalogue](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/identity-management-keyrock) states:

> It can be integrated with any development, specially with any Cloud service.

I would expect that KeyRock would be a generic component, that would allow us to add Single Sign-On authentication to our services. After KeyRock installation, however, I can see it's highly tied to FIWARE Lab:

- there is a FIWARE Lab menu at the top,
- I can see FIWARE-related content on logging in page,
- as an admin I can set users' FIWARE Lab account type (trial, community).

Is my assumption, that KeyRock can be used outside of FIWARE Lab context correct? Is there a way to brand it to my own purposes and turn off the FIWARE Lab-related functionalities? Or should it only be used as a part of FIWARE Lab instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the front end component (Horizon) is fixed to FIWARE look and field and FIWARE Lab user account policies. If you want to use it with your own GUI design you have to modify it yourself.

On the other hand the backend component (Keystone) can be used without changes as an "universal" idm.

BR